# Best Logging Performance

Tags: c#, logging, architecture

**I have the following environment:**

1. Windows XP Professional with .NET 2.0
2. Relativly old PC hardware (10 years old) with 3 GB memory.
3. A complex .NET based system consisting of many services, processes, local SQL server and WinForms GUI.

**The Problem:**

1. Each process/service logs data into its local file.
2. Each log gets immediately flushed to the file stream.
3. Sometimes when many processes log thousands of messages at the same time the performance of the PC gets bad because of severe file IO operations. Disabling the logging prooved that performance gets back to normal.

**Goal:**
Enhance the logging performance so that the system stays responsive.

My current solution idea:

1. Processes don't log to their local file directly, instead they send the log message to a local service using named pipes.
2. The local log service opens a named pipe and a corresponding worker thread for each process that has something to log.
3. The local log service caches the log messages that it receives from each process untill a configurable amount of log messages are available or a configurable amount of time has elapsed, then the log service writes all log messages to the corresponding process log files.

**What I am trying to achieve with this solution:**

1. The client execution is not blocked by a file IO write operation.
2. Log operations/calls will become asynchronous.
3. File access is controllable and happens only once after a configurable amount of time.

**Questions:**

1. Is this solution good? can the performance be enhanced further?
2. Are there any out of the box inter process logging libraries/frameworks?

Comment: I don't know about out of the box inter-process libraries, but you could look at buffering your writes within your process.  There are libraries that do that.  So, keep the logging per-process, but rather than write to disk on every Log.Write, buffer up 10/100/whatever and write them in blocks.  Log4Net, for example, can be configured to do this.That alone could greatly reduce your I/O time -- writing 50 entries sequentially in 1 call is going to take less time than 50 individual calls.  You could also make the bufferred writes async, just make sure you have a way to flush on exit.

Comment: Do above comment or install SP3 on XP so you can use up to .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Since you're constrained to .NET 2.0 look into `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` for [asynchronous operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx).

If it's possible try to multithread the application so the logger isn't working on the dispatcher thread.

If that still doesn't help then look into using PInvoke for C++ [OVERLAPPED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683.aspx) IO.